# Intra-process only WCF named pipe communication?

Tags: .net, wcf, security, appdomain, named-pipes

I've got a modular application that instantiates things in separate AppDomains and communicates with them over WCF pipes.  I don't want anyone outside of my process to be able to connect to these pipes.

Suggestions?

<edit>I don't know much about remoting -- would it be a terrible idea to write a transport that uses remoting under the hood?</edit>

Comment: You could *try* the [NullTransport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/NullTransportForWCF.aspx), but that might be same AppDomain-only

Comment: Named pipes only work on your local machine.  Are you afraid other apps on that machine will try to access your service?

Comment: I'm aware of that, and yes.  Potentially.  It's just something I'd like to secure if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I might be late... but better late than never :)
What you could do is sharing an object between your AppDomains... 
For example create a random GUID in the first one and send it to the second one (serialization...).
then, if both AppDomains know this auth token, you may do something like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Inspect client messages : add GUID in headers
/// </summary>
internal class CProcessAuthenticationClientInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{

    #region IClientMessageInspector Membres

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("ProcessAuth", "http://schemas.YOURCOMPANY.com/YOURAPPID", CProcessAuthenticationBehavior._authToken));
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Inspect server messages : Check GUID
/// </summary>
internal class CProcessAuthenticationDispatchInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{

    #region IDispatchMessageInspector Membres

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        Guid token = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<Guid>("ProcessAuth", "http://schemas.YOURCOMPANY.com/YOURAPPID");
        if (token != CProcessAuthenticationBehavior._authToken)
            throw new Exception("Invalid process");
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Add inspectors on both client and server messages
/// </summary>
public class CProcessAuthenticationBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Authentification token known by both sides of the pipe
    /// </summary>
    internal static Guid _authToken = Guid.NewGuid();

    #region IEndpointBehavior Membres

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CProcessAuthenticationClientInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CProcessAuthenticationDispatchInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then you just need to add your endpoint behaviour to your endpoint on both sides :

client :

```
ChannelFactory<TInterface> factory;
factory = new ChannelFactory<TInterface>(BuildLocalBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/foo");
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CProcessAuthenticationBehavior());
```

server :

```
ServiceHost svcHost = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(imlpementationType);
svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(interfaceType, binding, "net.pipe://localhost/foo");
svcHost.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new CProcessAuthenticationBehavior());
```

Well... this may be done in config, but I'll let you dig :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i haven't had to implement this, but looking back over my old question here, knowing what i know now, authenticating back to the central appdomain with a key passed to the other domains when they are set up would definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some security behaviors to your binding. They let you require authentication, sign the content and encrypt it, depending on your security needs.

See [WCF Security Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I get how these things work for WCF and how they can help secure it in general, but how can I accomplish my specific goal?

Answer (score 0):

> ... the netNamedPipeBinding binding, which provides cross-process
>   communication on the same machine. Named pipes do not work across
>   machines...

The [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752247%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) would accomplish your goals.

NetNamedPipeBinding [is optimized for on-machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) communication.

Comment: Aren't named pipes restricted to the local machine only?  You can't call a service that only communicates over pipes via another machine, right?

Comment: @Terry Donaghe: Yes, you're right, I was thinking about the bad-old days when we used to use named pipes proxied through tcp.....shudder.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm used NetNamedPipeBindings right now, but those are still open to users on the same machine.  AND the registered pipe URIs are discoverable I think.  I mean, I guess it's a negligible security concern, but I'd like to do SOMETHING with it if possible.

Comment: You could secure it like this: http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/06/23/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-3.aspx

Comment: Saw that, I'd have to set up a user for my service.  That's not securing it for the specific process, just for a user.